# RepositoryRestResource returns results in a different format than RepositoryRestController

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest, hateoas, hal

I am facing an issue with using different Spring Controllers.
We are using a standard Spring `PagingAndSortingRepository` annotated with `RepositoryRestResource` to serve search responses . One of the methods is

```
Page<Custodian> findByShortNameContainingIgnoreCase(@Param("shortName") String shortName, Pageable p);
```

It returns all entities of `Custodian` that satisfy the conditions grouped in Pages.

The result looks like this:

```html
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "custodians" : [ {
      "shortName" : "fr-custodian",
      "name" : "french custodian",
      "contact" : "Francoir",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/custodians/10004"
        },
        "custodian" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/custodians/10004"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/custodians/search/findByShortNameContainingIgnoreCase?shortName=fr&page=0&size=3&sort=shortName,asc"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 3,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

This is the format our frontend expects.

However, we need another query that results in a pretty long function (and thus URL) because it takes multiple parameters.
To be specific, it globally searches for a string in `Custodian`. So every parameter has the same value.

In order to shorten the URL we created a `RepositoryRestController` annotated with `ResponseBody` and implemented a function that takes only one parameter, calls the long URL internally and re-returns the result (a `Page`).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/custodian", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Custodian> search(@RequestParam(value = "keyWord") String keyWord, Pageable p) {
    return repo.LONGURL(keyWord, keyWord, p);
}
```

Unfortunately, Spring doesn't apply the same format to the result of our function.

It looks like this:

```html
{
  "content" : [ {
    "id" : 10004,
    "shortName" : "fr-custodian",
    "name" : "french custodian",
    "contact" : "Francoir",
  } ],
  "pageable" : {
    "sort" : {
      "sorted" : true,
      "unsorted" : false
    },
    "offset" : 0,
    "pageSize" : 3,
    "pageNumber" : 0,
    "unpaged" : false,
    "paged" : true
  },
  "totalElements" : 3,
  "totalPages" : 1,
  "last" : true,
  "size" : 3,
  "number" : 0,
  "sort" : {
    "sorted" : true,
    "unsorted" : false
  },
  "numberOfElements" : 3,
  "first" : true
}
```

How do you get Spring to deliver the same format in our custom method?

Comment: Welcome to SO! :-) Could you please post the implementation of the method with the shorter URL?